# Difference between concatenation types in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, concatenation

I'm trying to write my own transpose method. I'm wondering how the different forms of concatenation are affecting my code.

```
multi = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6],[7,9,8]]
new = Array.new(multi.length, [])
multi.each do |c|
    c.each_with_index do |x,y|
        new[y] += [x]
    end
end
new #=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [7, 9, 8]]
```

---

```
multi = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6],[7,9,8]]
new = Array.new(multi.length, [])
multi.each do |c|
    c.each_with_index do |x,y|
        new[y] << x
    end
end
new #=> [[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8], [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8], [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8]]
```

Why do they not work in an identical fashion?

Comment: Actually, both do not work as transpose. The first one looks like it does because you are using a special example that has the same number of rows and columns.

Comment: << this will work like appending means new[0] << 1 then new[0]  << 3 then new [0] << 5 .... so `new[0] =  [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8]`... same of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
new = Array.new(multi.length, [])
# => [[], [], []]
```

the elements in `new` refer to the same `Array` objects. Check their id:

```
new.map {|e| e.object_id}
# => [1625920, 1625920, 1625920]
```

The first code snippet gives you the expected result because `new[y] += [x]` assigns to `new[y]` a new `Array` object, so each element in `new` now doesn't refer to the same object:

```
new.map {|e| e.object_id}
# => [22798480, 22798440, 22798400]
```

With the second code snippet, each element in `new` still refers to the original `Array` object.